# Running django app + psql in vscode debugger causing FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: django, celery, psql, vscode-debugger

I have django app with psql database that I run with docker on port 5432.
When I run the app and celery worker using vscode debugger after a few requests I see this error

`psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already`

Can't reproduce same error when I run app in standard way by typing python3 main.py in CLI.

I used `sudo lsof -i:5432` and discovered that if I run app in standard way, processes are being constantly cleaned, but if I run it using VScode debugger, processes are getting stacked and list if getting bigger until I get FATAL.

Since I can only reproduce this error using VSCode debuger I assume it is related to that. Are there any settings to make debuger kill processes on the fly?